# String in array reads as not equal to same string from html form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, text-files

I'm writing a simple log in page that reads login info from a text file, and compares that to login info that a user enters into an html form.  The problem code below cycles through every line of the file, explodes it into an array composed of two elements (username and password), and then checks if those elements are equal to the strings entered by the user.

```
while (!feof($pass))
{
    $line = stripcslashes(fgets($pass));
    $data = explode(',', $line);
    echo 'username:'.$data[0].' password:'.$data[1];
    if ($user == trim($data[0]) AND $pwd == trim($data[1])) {echo'<p>Data Verified.  Access Granted!</p>'; $inBool = true; break;}
    else {echo ' - '.$user.' and '.$pwd.' are not in data array<br/>';$inBool = false;}
}
if ($inBool == false) {die('Error: username or password not found.');}
```

Instead of granting access when I enter text I literally copy pasted from the file, it passes through each line of the file, and outputs that it couldn't find my input.
[output printed into webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4UFn.png)

Edit: I have added code that prints the sha1 of the two strings.  They are definitely different, but I don't understand how or why.
sha1 of user input: 3d625d378f07476327e620548ff942eb72a42b8a
sha1 of file password: 753fe78c9dea1654263e5634224a33cc38338fb8

Comment: Use `var_dump` to make debug outputs - that will not only show you the type and value of a variable, but also the length in bytes. That usually makes it easier to spot if you have a problem with whitespace or other unprintable characters.

Comment: According to the screenshot, it appears to be the very first "record" in your file, that _should_ match the user input here, but doesn't? That could just be coincidence - or it could perhaps mean, that you saved your password file in encoding "UTF-8 with BOM"? If so, then change that to UTF-8 without a BOM - PHP still does not handle a BOM correctly when reading files.

Comment: `$line = stripcslashes(fgets($pass));` - what on earth is `stripcslashes` doing in there? Assuming my user password were to contain a \ - then why would you _falsify_ my password at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CBroe, using var_dump allowed me to find a " " at the end of the password read from the file.  Instead of using stripcslashes, which I had ignorantly assumed would only remove stuff like "\r\n", I used str_replace to get rid of any potential escape characters that I don't want, including the space.